# Is there a standard Kotlin function for splitting a Sequence into a head and a tail?

Tags: kotlin

I'm thinking of something with a signature like `fun <T> Sequence<T>.destruct(): Pair<T, Sequence<T>>?`  which would return `null` for an empty sequence, otherwise a pair of the first and rest of the receiver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer is "no." [This page](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/) lists all of the standard `Sequence` functions, and a search for "pair" doesn't turn up anything that seems to match what you want.

That said, there is a standard `firstOrNull()` function as well as a `drop()` function, so you could write your own pretty easily:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.destruct() =
    firstOrNull()?.let { it to drop(1) }
```

---

If you are working with sequences that can only be consumed once, the above won't work (as both `firstOrNull()` and (eventually) `DropSequence` will invoke the receiver's `iterator()` method). You could work around this by following the same general idea but being more explicit about how `iterator()` is called:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.destruct(): Pair<T, Sequence<T>>? {
    val iterator = iterator()
    
    return if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next() to iterator.asSequence()
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will consume the sequence twice, as `firstOrNull` and `drop` are both terminal

Comment: `drop` is not terminal: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/drop.html

Comment: Hmm, it isn’t. I suppose the problem is that firstOrNull has consumed it once, and then whoever uses the result will try to consume it again.

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor an honest question: how do you expect to access the first element of a sequence without invoking that sequence's iterator?

Comment: You could probably create your own `IteratorSequence` implementation where you pass the `Iterator` in directly, so that the underlying sequence's `iterator()` method is not invoked more than once. Then you could create a pair out of `iterator.next()` and `IteratorSequence(iterator)`.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question ;-)
Playing with this solution, you don't need `IteratorSequence` - `iterator.asSequence()` or `Sequence { iterator }` will do the trick.